# Mostrar las fechas por sobre 30 días en una tabla mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla mysql con fechas en formato Y-M-D y necesito contar cuantos de estas fechas estan por sobre 30 días,

Ejemplo:

Si en la tabla en el campo "fecha_inscritos" tengo una fecha de 2022-01-02 y el resto de las fechas estan dentro de los ultimos 30 dias , necesito contar ese dato y mostrar el resultado en una query, como puedo obtener ese dato?

Answer (score 1):

Según entendí, esto debería solucionar tu problema:

```
SELECT COUNT(fecha_inscritos) FROM american_sport WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),fecha_inscritos)>30
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

creo que lo que buscas es esto

```
SELECT 
COUNT(CASE WHEN resultado = 'Si' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS venta FROM (
SELECT IF( fecha_inscritos BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -30 DAY) AND CURDATE(),'Si','No') AS resultado
FROM contactos WHERE 1) AS temp
```

con la herramienta `date_add` te permite sacar los últimos 30 dias y empiezas a comparar, por último cuentas el resultando haciendo una tabla temporal, espero y te sirva

Comment: Yo lo deje como esta query:

SELECT 
COUNT(CASE WHEN resultado = 'Si' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) 
AS sin_pago_inscritos FROM (SELECT IF( fecha_ingreso BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), 
INTERVAL -30 DAY) AND CURDATE(),'Si','No') AS resultado
FROM american_sport WHERE 1) AS temp

Y el resultado me da como contando las fechas ingresadas los ultimos 30 días, yo necesito contar las fechas que tienen mas de 30 días, te agradezco tu ayuda Jose